# Bootstrap 4 carousel Doesn't behave as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I copied the code from Bootstrap website to create a simple carousel but it's not working, I don't understand why because I included Bootrap css, jquery and Bootstrap js from a CDN, here is the code of my index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kebabus</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

  <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="carousel-item active">
       <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://api.naans.fr/pictures/5a2bf196a2ca1747ec24ce82" alt="First slide">
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
       <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://api.naans.fr/pictures/5a2bf196a2ca1747ec24ce82" alt="Second slide">
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item">
       <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://api.naans.fr/pictures/5a2bf196a2ca1747ec24ce82" alt="Third slide">
     </div>
   </div>
   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
     <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
     <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
     <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
 </div>
</div>

<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have the following error in my browser console:

```
TypeError: f[0] is undefined
```

Comment: Include `popper.min.js` before `bootstrap.min.js`. click [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your snipet was that you used a version 3 bootstrap javascript with a version 4 html markup.

There you go, this is the v4 bootstrap carousel:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Kebabus</title>
        <base href="/">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://api.naans.fr/pictures/5a2bf196a2ca1747ec24ce82" alt="First slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://api.naans.fr/pictures/5a2bf196a2ca1747ec24ce82" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://api.naans.fr/pictures/5a2bf196a2ca1747ec24ce82" alt="Third slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script>
            $('.carousel').carousel({
                interval: 2000
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```